# Java, Format String with indexed whitespace

Tags: java

I have my String, "`08000001066`". 
This String, which is a telephone number should be displayed with correct format as, "`0800 000 1066`".

One person suggested i should use this code block,

```
DecimalFormatSymbols phoneNumberSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
phoneNumberSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat phoneNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###", phoneNumberSymbols);
```

This results in something close to what i want, but not exact as the `DecimalFormat` required a number (double, or float - of which a zero leading string cannot be parsed).

**How** would i format a String by method of something like Decimal Format's `####,###,###`?

Comment: You have two many digits in your example to format as ####,###,###. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String phoneNumber = "08000001066";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(phoneNumber)
            .insert(4," ")
            .insert(8," ");
        String output = sb.toString();
```

Comment: i prefer this answer as i can explicitly specificity the index of the whitespace. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it relies on your input being the correct number of digits but works with leading zeroes.

```
String inputString = "08000001066";

java.text.MessageFormat phoneFormat = new java.text.MessageFormat("{0} {1} {2}");
String[] phoneNumberArray = {inputString.substring(0,4), inputString.substring(4,7), inputString.substring(7)};

System.out.println(phoneFormat.format(phoneNumberArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})");
String s = "08000001066";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()) {
    return String.format("%s %s %s", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)));
}
```